# Scrape large html by chunks using python (with BeautifulSoup - or not). Memory constraint

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the followers list in Instagram with basic coding in Python, since I'm not expert neither in Python nor in HTML. So, my approach is simulating human like iterations.

Basically I'm using Selenium to open the Instagram followers page, used basic Python coding to scroll down the infinite scroll and BeautifulSoup to scrape the list.

The problem is that after hours of scrolling I reach my memory limit because the list is huge.

My current approach is:

- Get the infinite scroll window with: `elemWindow=browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.j6cq2')`
- I scroll down until ~30 new users appear in the list
- Get the whole page source: `pg1=browser.page_source`
- Use SoupStrainer and BeautifulSoup to get the whole list (used lxml because I searched here and people told it's faster, and it really is):

`strainer = SoupStrainer("a",{"class":"FPmhX notranslate zsYNt "})`

`elm1=bs4.BeautifulSoup(pg1, "lxml", parse_only=strainer)`

- Then I export to Excel only the new users that appeared (I have the last list length and the new list length, so I export the difference)

The main issue is that after some hours of scrolling the script stops at: `pg1=browser.page_source`, probably because it reached the memory limit.

So I'm trying to figure out how to keep in the computer memory only the HTML chunk of the new users that appeared after scrolling down, and scrape the small list from this html chunk.

I searched here about ElementTree's `iterparse` and `htmltext.split`, but it was not clear for me if this is the path to follow...

Comment: why don't you use the builtin selenium methods to get the element `FPmhX notranslate zsYNt`?

Comment: I could get the list of users in this element (FPmhX notranslate zsYNt) without keeping the whole page source (pg1=browser.page_source)? Or those builtin selenium methods search this element in the whole page source too? Because I think the issue is that the page source and the user list is too big for the computer memory... That's why I'm trying to do a script that analyze only the new chunk generated by the scroll down.

Comment: yes the builtin methods search the whole page. But you can use the xpath selector to select the last `N` elements. Here is an example `//a[@class="FPmhX notranslate zsYNt " and position()>last()-30]` . Update the xpath accordingly.

Comment: I'm testing your suggestion isolated before try to run the whole script. So, elem1 = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='FPmhX notranslate zsYNt ']") worked to find the whole list. To add the position part I did this: elem1 = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='FPmhX notranslate zsYNt ']")[position()>last()-5] and got this error: NameError: name 'position' is not defined. Then I did this, which seems to be the right format: elem1 = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='FPmhX notranslate zsYNt '][position() > last() - 5]"), but it kept getting the whole list. What's wrong?

Comment: try this xpath it should work `/descendant-or-self::a[@class='FPmhX notranslate zsYNt '][position()>last()-5]`   . Make use of `/descendant-or-self`

Comment: It worked (I dont know what it means, but I'll search later). Now I'll try to incorporate in my script. I'll get back here after the test. Thanks for now!

Comment: Unfortunately this approach didnt work. The script crashed at the same time as my old script. I tried to find the last positions by xpath and class, but both crashed. Any other suggestion to deal with this memory issue? Because the page loads more followers after the crash, but the script seems to consume all the memory at some point...

Comment: Check the networks tab for the request made by the website to load new followers, and try to duplicate that with the python requests library

Comment: I searched about it and tried but I have no clue how to do this. Every time I scroll down and the page loads more followers, the network tab shows a GET method type json and after that a lot of GET methods type jpeg (users' photos). I dont know how to link the response headers with the name of the followers. Because it seems to be the same everytime: content-length: 1872 / content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 / and so on.... As you can see, I'm not familiar with this library nor http... Any help?

Comment: this should help https://github.com/instagrambot/instabot